# How can I add ACL entry comments on a Cisco 3750?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, cisco-catalyst

I'm trying to find the best way to add comments into my access-lists. For the moment, the only maneer I found is the following one:

```
switch#conf t
switch(config)#ip access-list extended VLAN-TEST3
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark first remark
switch(config-ext-nacl)#10 permit ip any any
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark second remark
switch(config-ext-nacl)#20 deny ip any any
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark third remark
```

But by using this, I'm unable to see the comments with the command `sh ip access-list VLAN-TEST3` they appear only when I do a `sh run` (which isn't the most practical to see an ACL). I also cannot specify a number of line for the remark and I can't modify/delete them.

What is the best way to do that? I'm using a Cisco 3750

Comment: You'll probably have better luck reaching the target audience of your question at the [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.